# Launch php file from php as background process without exec()

Tags: php, background, exec

I want to run a PHP script in the background using another PHP script.

I had this in mind:

```
exec('/usr/bin/php background.php &');
```

My webhost has only disabled access to exec().

The only other way I can think of is sending a mail() to an email forwarder which is piped to a script, but that's rather a wacky workaround than a solution.

Does anyone know any solution?

Comment: have you tried `system()` or `shell_exec()` ?

Comment: Yes, they're also disabled. And backticks too.

Comment: I can't see any solution to do a background process

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could achieve that by using curl and loading the script as a web resource so it can be executed.
If that script needs to be protected from public, you can check if the request came from the same server:

```
if( $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] != 'localhost' 
        || $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] != '127.0.0.1'
        || stripos( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'wget' )===false
        )
{
    // Access Denied!!
    die();
}
```

Be sure to make an asynchronous request with curl, so if the script takes a lot of time to execute, doesn't hang the original user request (use `curl_setopt( $handle, CURLOPT_HEADER, false );`

So the plan is from the page where you know you need to execute the script, launch an Http request to the script (this is a very basic example of using curl library):

```
$handle = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $handle, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost/your_script.php');
curl_setopt( $handle, CURLOPT_HEADER, false );
curl_exec( $handle );
curl_close( $handle );
```

Then in your script, use the above script to protect requests not comming from current server, and do the job.

**Updated**
As stated in this question: [sending a non-blocking HTTP POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555517/sending-a-non-blocking-http-post-request)
In your script job you could send this header to close the connection as script is running:

```
// Send the response to the client
header('Connection: Close');
// Do the background job: just don't output anything!
```

**Updated II**
Reviewing my own answer, I've checked that `curl_setopt( $handle, CURLOPT_HEADER, false );` does not create an asynchronous request. I still have not found how to do it.

Comment: Thank you for your nice answer!
Only, it still keeps waiting for the background process to finish. Is there any way I could set something like a timeout of 0 seconds in cURL?

Comment: Ah, got it! `curl_setopt( $handle, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1);`
It does generate a race condition however; If it takes longer than 1 second to connect this won't work.
Also. it keeps the user waiting for one extra second, but I guess I'll just have to accept that.

Comment: You'll need to develop a way that will block second visitor for running the background request if the job is still working.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a possible way to close connection once script is reached.

Comment: Thank you sir clinisbut. This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: you can use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 1);` note that it is in mili-seconds. (cURL 7.16.2 or higher and PHP 5.2.3 or above)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this, but if you are able to use curl, you could possibly create background.php with `ignore_user_abort()` and curl it from your main script with a low timeout. The script the user sees will be delayed slightly because it has to wait for the curl request to timeout, but your background should continue working.