# Ajax call inside each loop

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I found many posts with this topic. But the solutions I found is not much unsuitable for me. Some experts advised to change code structure, but I am not sure how can I do that.

**What I want:**
1) Get a list of movie from SQL database
2) Fetch information from a website for each movie

**Problem I face:** PHP MAX_TIMEOUT occurs.

**Solution I thought:** call async req for each movie, separately

**Bottleneck:** Too many async requests

Can you please advice how to implement that (if possible only JS, not jquery please)?

**Some solutions from web:**

1) Use ASYNC = FALSE.... I don't want to use SYNC req, pointless of using Ajax then
2) Collect all data, then make Ajax call once ... well, I did that first .. but it is a long script (fetching movie info from web), so ultimately causing PHP MAX_TIMEOUT
3) increase PHP MAX_TIMEOUT ... not feasible, I don't know how much to increase.

**JS**

```
function loadData(mArray){
    mArray = [{"movieid":"1","title":"10 Things I Hate About You"},{"movieid":"2","title":"100 Girls"}]; // TO SIMLYFY, I PUT THIS CODE HERE .. NORMALLY I GET THIS ARRAY USING ANOTHER AJAX CALL
    for (var i = 0; i < mArray.length; i++) { 
        var obj = mArray[i];
        webAjaxcall(obj["mid"],obj["title"]);  // DEFINITELY NOT A GOOD IDEA
    }
    return true;
}

function webAjaxcall(mid,title){
    var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
            //DO SOMETHING
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST","file2.php",true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    params = "title="+title+"&mid="+mid;
    xmlhttp.send(params);
}
```

**Just in case anybody wants to know how I populate the JS array:**

**FILE 1**

```
$sql = "SELECT `movieid`,`title` FROM movielist";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $output[] = $row;
    }
    exit(json_encode($output));
```

**FILE 2**

```
$json=file_get_contents("http://www.website.com/?t=".rawurlencode($moviename));
$info=json_decode($json);
DO SOMETHING
```

**AJAX TO GET MOVIELIST**

```
var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
var myarr;
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
        myarr = xmlhttp.responseText;
        loadData(JSON.parse(myarr));
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("POST","file1.php",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
params = "fname=<?php echo $ses_id;?>";
xmlhttp.send(params);
```

Comment: when you are calling your loadData function? on window load or something else???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note:** `ASYNC = FALSE` means *synchronous*, which means everything is going to happen in sequence, one call waiting for the previous, and ultimately results in blocking code.

**Solution / Opinion:** assuming that the site (or API) where you're pulling data can't handle multiple results in a single request, the only way you'll be able to handle this volume of looping ajax requests is to cache the ajax results directly in your SQL db:

**`::pseudo-architecture::`**

Let's assume the following PHP files:

**index.php**

- Displays your results
- Handles loop logic to display your movies using a single SQL query
- Results that are not cached display a "loading" indicator
- Write a `$(document).ready()` function that loops through all the "not-cached" movies, asynchronously calls **get.php** with appropriate `GET` parameters for each entry that wasn't already cached. This way it doesn't affect the page load time, as it occurs after the page has already loaded.

`::pseudocode::`

```
for movie in movies
    if object has cached data and date retrieved is less than [some time ago]
        return data from SQL db
    else
        display a "caching in progress" notification for that title
        send GET request to get.php
```

*Note: you might need to queue/delay your requests to get.php depending on how powerful your server is, lest you get 1000 separate threads running at once.*

**get.php**

- Example url: http://www.yoursite.com/get.php?name=superman&year=1980
- Retrieves `$_GET` parameters sent from your index.php's ajax loop and forwards a request to your 3rd party API/website.
- You want this to be asynchronous, throwing a *connection-close* ASAP [(see how to do that)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555517/sending-a-non-blocking-http-post-request)
- Think of this like an API "proxy"

`::pseudocode::`

```
send 200 ok status code and connection-close header
get $_GET parameters
retrieve API data for your movie by sending $_GET parameters
cache to your SQL db once data is returned
```

Ultimately, the page loads in realtime, and in order to see the new data, you'd need to refresh the page (or if you want to get REALLY fancy, do something with [WebSockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) that notifies the client).

Comment: thanks r3mus .. 1) u r right, that's why I don't want to use SYNC req ... 2) I edited and try to make it simpler, if it happens in actual. However, main concern is I have let say 1000 movies to collect data and I have to do it one by one .... 3) the API does not handle multiple result in a single request. the solution u proposed is little difficult for me, but I will try to understand and implement. Thanks. ...

Comment: 1) OK, so you'd actually want `async = true` ;)  2) Still complicated, but given the solution, I don't think your example needs to be more clear 3) I'll see if I can expand the pseudo to make it more clear.